# Fatal error using Grunt Watch to convert SASS to CSS

Tags: gruntjs, task, contains, watch, compass

I'm using Grunt to live convert my SASS files to CSS via watch.

The thing is: I can run the Compass task normaly, the CSS is created very well, but when I use WATCH I got the error:

> grunt.util._.contains is not a function

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "myName",
    "description": "myDesc",
    "author": "mySelf",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "^1.0.1",
        "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.1.1",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.5.1",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.4.4"
    }
}
```

Here's my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        compass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: 'assets/**/*.{scss,sass}',
                tasks: ['compass']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['compass','watch']);
};
```

I try a lot of changes but nothing helps

> **Update!**
>
> After a long night, **solve the problem**... Please read my own answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem! The ^4.0 `lodash` version has changed **contains** to **includes**, and the `grunt-contrib-watch` uses the old lodash syntax. So I changed only one line in the code. Find 
`node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/tasks/watch.js` on line 116:

Old line:

> if (!grunt.util._.**contains**(target.options.event, 'all') && !grunt.util._.**contains**(target.options.event, status)) {

New line:

> if (!grunt.util._.**includes**(target.options.event, 'all') && !grunt.util._.**includes**(target.options.event, status)) {

Now the Watch with Compass/SASS works like a charm ;)

I hope it helps someone!